# lein pom - :classifier clause does not get generated in pom.xml

Tags: clojure, maven-2, pom.xml, dependency-management, leiningen

I'm using the Stanford CoreNLP library, and for this I need to use a classifier clause. In a pom.xml, it should look like this :

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To achieve this, my `project.clj` looks like this :

```
(defproject sviepbd "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]

                 ;; [...] other dependencies


                 ;; Stanford CoreNLP
                 [edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp "3.5.0"] ;; A Suite of Core Natural Language Processing Tools
                 [edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp "3.5.0" :classifier "models"]
                 ]
  :main ^:skip-aot sviepbd.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

After running `lein deps`, the dependencies get fetched properly, and I can use them when working in the REPL. However, after running `lein pom` it is my constatation that **the `classifier`clause does not appear in the generated pom.xml**.

What have I done wrong?

I'm using Leiningen 2.3.4; the reason I need a proper pom.xml is that I'm using Counterclockwise as an editor.

Comment: Seems to work with Leiningen 2.5.0. Maybe it's a bug that has since been fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on Leiningen 2.5.0; anyone with that issue should [upgrade](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#installation).